# Find $x$ in a logarithmic equation

Tags: logarithms

> Find $x$ in $\log((x+2)^2) = 2$ where $x > 0$

I began with

$$10^{\log\left((x+2)^2\right)} = 10^2$$

$$(x+2)^2= 100$$

I can do the algebra,but I don't how to apply the restriction.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $\log((x+2)^2)$ or $\log^2(x+2)$?

Comment: The first one, let me edit the question.

Comment: Just work out the problem without the restriction, finding all solutions, then apply the restriction at the end.

Comment: Why do you multiply the LHS with $10$? Did you mean to write it as $10^{\log((x + 2)^2)}$ instead?

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2+4x+4=100$$

$$x^2+4x-96=0$$

$$(x-8)(x+12)=0$$

So, $x=8$ and $x=-12$.

$8>0$, but $-12 \ngtr 0$, so applying the restriction, $x=8$

Answer (score 1):

$$(x+2)^2 = 100$$

$$x+2 = \pm 10$$
$$x=-2\pm10=-12 \text{ or} 8$$

Since $x>0$, reject $x=-12$ as a solution and hence $x=8$.

Comment: oh dear, i keep making mistakes. thanks.

Comment: Are you sure we will reject the $x=-12$? In the original problem statement we have $\log((x+2)^2)$ so if $x=-12$ we still get $\log(100)$. I believe if the original problem was written as $2\log(x+2)$ then we would discard the $-12$

Comment: the constraint where $x>0$ is imposed right?

Comment: oh, I did not read the entire question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you multiplied by $10$ on one side, while performed exponentiation on the other in the first step. Did you mean:

$$10^{\log\left((x+2)^2\right)} = 10^2$$
$$(x+2)^2 = 100 \rightarrow x^2+4x-96 =0\rightarrow (x+12)(x-8)=0$$

To get $x=8$ as the solution since $-12<0$. Regardless, you can also apply some logarithm properties to avert the quadratic completely:

$$\log\left((x+2)^2\right)=2\log(x+2)=2$$

Thus giving:

$$\log(x+2)=1$$

And to get rid of the logarithm (assuming base $10$):

$$10^{\log(x+2)}=10^1\rightarrow x+2=10$$

So $x=8$, which is greater than $0$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is base $10$ logarithmic we are talking here.  If so, $\log_{10}(x+2)^2 = 2$ means $(x+2)^2 = 10^2$. Similarly, $\ln(x+2)^2=\log_{e}(x+2)^2 = 2$ means $(x+2)^2 = e^2$. The rest is just algebra.